# Quickly filter massive numpy-like arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'll let the code explain what I'm trying to do - I think it's pretty straightforward:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = (1e5 * np.random.rand(int(1e4))).astype(int)
arr2 = (1e5 * np.random.rand(int(1e3))).astype(int)
arr3 = np.random.rand(int(1e4))

maskFn = lambda val: val in arr2
maskArr = np.vectorize(maskFn)(arr1)

outArr = arr3[maskArr]
```

My solution is fine for small quantities of data, but I'm heaving around so pretty heavy arrays now, and the lag on my amateur code is overwhelming. A more disk-based solution that minimises memory overhead would be good too - I'm not memory-limited yet, but I expect I will be soon...

Any help would be **super** appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn’t assign a lambda to a variable. I’m guessing that this code is just an example? Where is your data coming from in your program?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is not an efficiency tool - even if the disclaimer is hidden in a note.  `arr3[[(val in arr2) for val in arr1]]` does the same thing, right?  And probably just as fast?

Comment: This code is just an example, yes. The data is coming from an hdf file on disk and is of the same types and similar shapes as what seen is seen here. I've confirmed that I/O slowness is not the problem.

`arr3[[(val in arr2) for val in arr1]]` does seem to be just as fast - or, indeed, just as slow!

It's the solution I tried first; I changed to using `np.vectorize` in the vain hope that it would be quicker.

Out of curiosity, why shouldn't I assign a lambda to a variable? I know it's not necessary to do so, but if it makes the code easier to read, why not?

Comment: Assigning a lambda to a variable (or not) is just a style thing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the function I need!

It's `np.isin`. It's orders of magnitude quicker, and more importantly, it scales appropriately with very large arrays. Example solution:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = (1e5 * np.random.rand(int(1e4))).astype(int)
arr2 = (1e5 * np.random.rand(int(1e3))).astype(int)
arr3 = np.random.rand(int(1e4))

maskArr = np.isin(arr1, arr2)

outArr = arr3[maskArr]
```

This is even quicker if the array values are unique (like dictionary keys): you can flag `assume_unique = True` in `np.isin` and it uses a more efficient algorithm. (The example arrays provided here are not unique, of course, but the ones in my actual dataset are.)

Thanks to those who responded to my first ever Stack Overflow code question! Your helpful hints prodded me in the right direction. Indeed, just explaining my problem 'out loud', as it were, was a big help.